# Does not display the message using JSON AJAX php online

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a problem with this code,
the idea is to press the btn_verify button and it shows me a message "This is JSON", the strange thing is that the program runs in localhost,
but when uploading to the hosting does not run and does not show the message
What is the reason?
I have other programs that use the same structure and libraries and run well 
in both forms: local and in the hosting.

my code is:

//HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Resultados</title>

<style type="text/css">
 td{font-family: Arial; font-size: 9pt;}
</style>

<style type="text/css">
  th{font-family: Arial; font-size: 9pt;}
</style>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" name="btn_verificar" id="btn_verificar"  class="btn 
btn-info">Verificar</button>

<div class="the-return">

</div>

<script src="public/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>                           
<script src="public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/functions.js"></script>

   <script>
    $(document).on('click','#btn_verificar',function(){
      $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#btn_verificar').click(function(){  

       var id=$('#id_pedido').val();//take id about one record and it is ok

       //alert(id); show id and this out it's right

      $.ajax({
         method:"POST",
         url:"verificarResultados.php",        
         data:{id:id},
         dataType:"JSON",        
         success:function(data)
          {            
             alert(data.result);

             $(".the-return").html("Message:" + data["result"]);

          }//end  success        
      }); //end  ajax   
    });// end document ready
  });//end on click

 </script>
 </body>
</html>



 //file verificarResultados.php

 <?php

  if(isset($_POST["id"]))
   {    
     $rows = array("result" => 'This is JSON');
     echo json_encode($rows);             
   }   
 ?>
```

Comment: did you try looking in the web console of your browser?

Comment: does the alert work? can u console log the data? can u look at the network tab in your console and look at what was sent and what was received ? Why do you have document.ready within a .click function??? Do you get any javascript errors in console???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Where is the `#id_pedido` element?

Comment: Thanks for your comments:alert(data.result);

Comment: If something works locally, but then suddenly not remotely... console is your friend! Please do what Miggy and Andrew suggested and report back.

Comment: @Miggy,@Andrew, alert(data.result); and $(".the-return").html("Message:" + data["result"]);
on ly work in localhost when upload to the hosting does not work,

Comment: Dear @Jorge Guberte, #id_pedido it is a number of record an we take with this line:<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id_pedido" value="<?php echo $datosPaciente[0]["ped_id"]; ?>" />

Comment: Did you find anything using web console? Also, if you're using the exact code in your hosting it won't work because as @JorgeGuberte said the element with an id `id_pedido` is missing. Maybe that what's causing the problem

Comment: Thanks @Randall  but I thought that the console only let to view the values  only when the application is working locally

Comment: Dear @Miggy the line  alert(id) show the id in localhost and also online, the problem is that these 2 lines does not work in the hosting    
            alert(data.result);
             $(".the-return").html("Message:" + data["result"]);

Comment: Could you please show us the we console. if something is wrong, it will show something. Look into console tab and network tab. it will show the data that is being returned in your ajax and we can start their to fix the problem

Comment: @Miggy in the console show this: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/xavsil1/carpenterweb.net/verificarResultados.php:1) in <b>/home/xavsil1/carpenterweb.net/class/class.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/xavsil1/carpenterweb.net/verificarResultados.php:1) in <b>/home/xavsil1/carpenterweb.net/verificarResultados.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
{"result":"This is JSON 09\/10"}

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
       method:"POST",
       url:"verificarResultados.php",        
       data:{id:id},
       dataType:"JSON",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, result, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```